# I am trying to input a timestamp from my Android app onto Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to input a timestamp from my Android application onto Cloud Firestore. Currently I am using this code:

The code currently does not add to the correct timestamp field on the Firestore collection for sessions. It adds two new fields on the collection which is not what I am looking for. Any suggestions would be great.

SessionAdapter code:

```
  public void filterList(ArrayList<Session> filteredList) {
    sessionList = filteredList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

class SessionHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView textViewModule;
    TextView textViewTitle;
    TextView textViewDate;
    TextView textViewStart;
    TextView textViewEnd;



    public SessionHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textViewModule = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_student_name);
        textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_course);
        textViewDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_student_ID);
        textViewStart = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_user_UID);
        textViewEnd = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_end);
```

Here is my session model class:

```
    public class Session {


private String module, Title;
private String room;
private String date;
private String startTime1;
private String endTime1;
private String documentID;


private java.util.Date start;
private java.util.Date end;

private Date startTime;
private Date endTime;
 public Session(){}

public Session(String title, String date, String documentID, String    endTime1, String module, String room, String startTime1 ) {
    this.documentID = documentID;
    this.module = module;
    this.Title = title;
    this.date = date;
    this.startTime1 = startTime1;
    this.endTime1 = endTime1;
    this.room = room;
}

public Session(String title, String date, String endTime1, String module, String room, String startTime1 ) {
    this.module = module;
    this.Title = title;
    this.date = date;
    this.startTime1 = startTime1;
    this.endTime1 = endTime1;
    this.room = room;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return Title;
}

public String getModule(){
    return module;
}

public String getRoom(){
    return room;
}

public String getDate(){
    return date;
}

public Date getStartTime(){
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
    formatter.setTimeZone(timezone);
    return startTime;
}

public Date getEndTime(){
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
    formatter.setTimeZone(timezone);
    return endTime;
}

@Exclude
public String getDocumentID(){
 return documentID;
}
```

Comment: you can use the inbuilt firestore function for timestamp Timestamp.now()

Comment: I don't want the current Time I am looking to set my own one @deepak kumar

Answer (score 0):

You have these two fields in your class:

```
private Date startTime;
private Date endTime;
```

But you never assign their values anywhere in the class.  They are always null.  You have methods that return their values, for example:

```
public Date getStartTime(){
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London");
    formatter.setTimeZone(timezone);
    return startTime;
}
```

But the method just returns null, because startTime never gets assigned.  It looks like you're trying to format a date here, but it's not actually doing anything.

If you want to write a timestamp to Firestore, you're going to have to come up with an actual Date object the at represents the point in time you want to write.

Comment: The class is a model class used only for retrieval methods. How would I go about achieving this Doug. I have a class with blank fields to add a title then start and end time etc so I type these in and it returns only todays date and time in the start and end time fields?

Comment: You would also need setter methods for all the fields that you're trying to read.  The getter methods are not enough.

Comment: And after I implement the setter methods how would I implement these into setting the TimeStamp and then retrieving it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I currently have a class set up and laid out to accept user input for the relevant fields. I want to take what I type into the fields and use this to update my TimeStamp

Comment: how do I get 'an actual Date object' that will accept the time I am inputting for TimeStamp

Comment: That sounds like a good thing to ask as a whole new question here.